# `Certain proteins will use microtubes as tracks for laying out organelles in a cell`

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does the following sentence mean, especially last part?

> Certain proteins will use microtubes as **tracks** for **laying out**
>   organelles in a cell.

Comment: -1.  I can see how the phrase "for laying out" might have given some trouble. But you haven't demonstrated any effort here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proteins will use the nanotubes as **guidelines** or **templates** (guiding them as a **train track** guides a train); they will place (lay out) the organelles *along* the nanotubes (I don't know if this  means **in** the nanotubes, or **on** the nanotubes, but definitely **in the same direction or configuration as** the nanotubes.)

Comment: It has nothing to do with microbes but I got the sense which is easy to understand now. Thank you so much

Comment: Oops.  Changed  "microbes" to  "proteins" as in your title quote. And—you're welcome!